# How to fix dropdown not displaying on click?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a static website with HTML, but the CSS framework was built for me via a free theme builder. Now it's time for me to implement the framework successfully. I'm using [Bootstrap Builder](https://bootstrap.build/) with their documentation to form my CSS, and from there adding additional content I need. I'm trying to add a dropdown in my Navbar, but for some reason the example they give me isn't working, but their demo/example does. I've copied their code line-for-line and haven't been able to get the example to even work. The sample code I share below is for a button dropdown, the only difference is using the btn class, but the code otherwise is exactly the same for a Navbar dropdown.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#dropdownMenuLink" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect that when I click on the dropdown, the items listed would display in a ... well... dropdown.

Expected results:
[Untoggled/Not Clicked](https://prnt.sc/n9yayd) and
[Toggled/Clicked](https://prnt.sc/n9ybk8), without the green square around it obviously.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you please post some code so We can see what are you doing.
Just Once suggestion by reading your question is
Please check you used Jquery and Bootstrap js CDN or files or not?

Comment: I'm pulling the CSS from file, using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">`

Comment: Only CSS will not help you dear, Please include Jquery and Bootstrap JS as well then this drop down will work

Comment: Did you visit the Bootstrap Builder I linked in my question? Download options for themes include `.css` and `.scss` file types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap uses javascript for few components. In the case of dropdowns it uses popper.js so if you want to make the dropdown work you will need to add popperjs script. It is documented here.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

also all components which are JS dependent are listed in this link.

Answer (score 0):

At First Please Check your CDN order Whether you added the CDNS Appropiately or not

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
<a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" 
id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

If Everything okay just remove the link reference  from

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" 
id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
```

It will work fine.Hope It helps you

Comment: To note, as I did above, my CSS is coming from a stylesheet, not a CDN. Second, what do you mean by "remove the link reference"? Should it read as
```html
<a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" 
id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>``` , without the `href="#"`?

Comment: yes try  not adding the href

Comment: The correct path was to get PopperJS and jQuery, as well as BootstrapJS. Not sure why my Bootstrap Builder didn't mention it.